# Xamarin.Forms ListView on specific position

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

We are working with ListView in Xamarin.From and showing it as a dropdown, but we are not able to get drop down specific position, tried absolute layout also to achieve it?

Comment: Question is bit confusing! you have added listview inside dropdown or dropdown as listview itemtemplate? "we are not able to get drop down specific position" - which means you are not able to get selectedIndex ?

Comment: @Dineshkumar We have a ListView which we want to use as a drop down for Xamarin.Forms(IOS)

Comment: Can you share some code what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two way.

First way is to use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/)

RelativeLayout is used to position and size views relative to properties of the layout or sibling views. Unlike AbsoluteLayout, RelativeLayout does not have the concept of the moving anchor and does not have facilities for positioning elements relative to the bottom or right edges of the layout. RelativeLayout does support positioning elements outside of its own bounds.

For example

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <BoxView Color="Red" x:Name="redBox"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Height,Factor=.15,Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.8,Constant=0}" />
    <BoxView Color="Blue"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
            ElementName=redBox,Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
            ElementName=redBox,Property=X,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.5,Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.5,Constant=0}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: RelativeLayout sample]

Another way is to use a Grid. If you have to add a ListView near an Entry (for example) you can add Entry and ListView in two "row" one under the other, and set the height of ListView using Grid.Span. I don't know it this works well... but you can try. Otherwise add a RelativeLayout inside a Grid's Cell then add your Entry and ListView to this RelativeLayout.

You have some exercises to do now ;)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, will try it out